# How can I send a Flux of messages as individual requests using WebClient?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

How can `WebClient` be used to send individual requests when working with `Flux`?

I have a `Flux<Message>` that must be sent as individual HTTP requests because of the HTTP API that it is interacting with. Moreover, I am interested in the result of each request so I need store the response for each message in a `MessageResponse` for further processing.

I attempted the following solution, however it to my understanding it batches multiple `Message`s in a single request. In contrast, I need to make sure to execute multiple requests of single messages:

```java
Flux<Message> messages = // ...

Flux<MesssageResponse> = webClient
   .post()
   .uri(messageUri)
   .header(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
   .body(messages, Message.class)
   .retrieve()
   .bodyToFlux(MessageResponse.class);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your send request function to take a single message and return `Mono<MessageResponse>` as a result of request

```java
public Mono<MessageResponse> sendRequest(Message message) {
    return webClient
            .post()
            .uri(messageUri)
            .header(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .bodyValue(message)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(MessageResponse.class);
}
```

And on your flux of messages use `.flatMap()`

```java
Flux.just(new Message(), new Message(), new Message())
        .flatMap(message -> sendRequest(message))
        // flux of results ...
```

So that you'll get the flux of individual request results

Comment: Thanks! One observation though, the `message` parameter needs to be wrapped in a publisher, e.g. `.body(Mono.just(message), Message.class)`. Alternatively, the `.bodyValue(message)` can be leveraged.

Comment: Of course, I forgot about it. Just edited my answer